# htaccess rewrite rule returns error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file which dynamically generates a sitemap:

```
<?php
$do = "2way";
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password"); 

mysql_select_db("database",$db);
$sql = "select * from url_urls WHERE private = 'n' AND short = '$do'"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$date = date('c',time());
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1"); 
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">
";

{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $short = $row["url_code"];
echo "   <url>
      <loc>http://$do/$short</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<lastmod>$date</lastmod>
  </url>
";
}
}
?>
</urlset>
```

It which works as it should with htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

I need to add the following lines to the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|ttf|eot|xml|svg|woff)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_code=$1 [L]
```

But when I put them together like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|ttf|eot|xml|svg|woff)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_code=$1 [L]
Rewriterule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

The php file no longer generates the sitemap. Obviously the htaccess is the problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of rules and include `php` in excluded list:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|ttf|eot|xml|svg|woff)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url_code=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's always the simplest of answers isn't it! Cheers, great help